# How to restore database EF migration tools

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I got a database, and accidentally I deleted the __MigrationHistory table.
Now the program throws error, and I can't loss all the datas.
Is there anyway to restore the table that I deleted??
Will I lost all my database?

I added the __MigrationHistory manually, and now this is the error:

> Additional information: Unable to update database to match the current
>   model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is
>   disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based
>   migration or enable automatic migration. Set
>   DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable
>   automatic migration

Comment: can you catch the error that it throws, and post it so that we might know what it is?

Comment: the `__MigrationHistory` table should only be an issue if you are trying to do a new migration, or if you are auto-migrating your database every startup. Either way, the error will tell us what needs to change.

Comment: Its trying to recreate all the database, it says it can't create tables

Comment: I added the __MigrationHistory manually, and now this is the error: Additional information: Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.

Comment: Did u try to simply delete your migration and your database... type in the consol :
add-migration init
update-databse

Comment: Have you tried setting `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true`, and then call `Update-Database`? You do this in the `Configuration.cs` constructor inside your Migrations directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can "reset" the state of your migrations in your project.  You will essentially be creating a migration state where Entity Framework believes that the current state of your database is the "first" migration.  Note, however, that this will limit your ability to roll back to previous versions of the app with an earlier migration state.

1. Delete the existing migrations from the migrations folder in your project.
2. Delete the __MigrationHistory table in the database (Already Done).
3. Run the following command in the Package Manager Console: `add-migration Reset`. because the migrations folder does not contain any previous migrations, the `Reset` migration will be a full script of the models in their current state.  **Important** Verify that this `Up` method matches exactly the current database table state.
4. In the `Reset` migration, comment out everything in the `Up` method.  We don't want to run the `Up` method, because the Database should already match this.
5. Run the `update-database` command.  This will create a new `__MigrationHistory` table and create a new line in the table, indicating that the database is matching this `Reset` migration step.  It won't make any changes to the database, however, since the `Up` method is empty.
6. ***(optional)*** Remove the comments around the `Up` method in the `Reset` migration, so that new databases can be scripted to this point.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to maintain your migration history

1. If you both deleted content and structure of _MigrationHistory, create an empty _MigrationHistory with

> ```
> CREATE TABLE [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] (
>     [MigrationId]    NVARCHAR (150)  NOT NULL,
>     [ContextKey]     NVARCHAR (300)  NOT NULL,
>     [Model]          VARBINARY (MAX) NOT NULL,
>     [ProductVersion] NVARCHAR (32)   NOT NULL,
>     CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.__MigrationHistory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MigrationId] ASC, [ContextKey] ASC)
> );
> ```

1. Comment the contents of the Up() methods of all your migration code files
2. Run the `update-database` command: it will refill `__MigrationHistory` without attempting to do anything else
3. Uncomment what you commented in your migration code files in order to create the db model when you will deploy on a new database

Answer (score 1):

Point your scripts to another empty database. Run all your migrations. Copy table and data from `__MigrationHistory` into your production database.

Answer (score 1):

To restore __MigrationHistory Table with all versions (from migrations folder), do the following steps

```
update-database -script
```

This will produce sql script to drop and create tables, procedures include migration table
In the above script, remove all sql commands related to all other tables, procedures.
Keep only sql commands related to __MigrationHistory Table.

After removing all sql commands not related to migration table, it contains creation of migration table and some insert statements. It looks like

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] (
[MigrationId] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
[ContextKey] [nvarchar](300) NOT NULL,
[Model] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
[ProductVersion] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.__MigrationHistory] PRIMARY KEY ([MigrationId], [ContextKey]))
```

Now run this script in your sql server and the __MigrationHistory Table will be created (restored for you) with all versions.